# Default value in calculated field

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got an SQL query that works great, unless there are 0 records found. Is there any way to make "ttlTotal" = 0? Currently it returns NULL when there are no records found.

```
SELECT
  UserName,
  SUM(ifNull(Day1Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day2Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day3Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day4Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day5Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day6Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day7Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day1OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day2OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day3OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day4OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day5OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day6OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day7OT, 0)) as ttlTotal
FROM weeks
WHERE RecNum = 1
AND
  (Day1Reg IS NOT NULL OR
   Day1OT IS NOT NULL OR
   Day2Reg IS NOT NULL OR
   Day2OT IS NOT NULL OR
   Day3Reg IS NOT NULL OR
   Day3OT IS NOT NULL OR
   Day4Reg IS NOT NULL OR
   Day4OT IS NOT NULL OR
   Day5Reg IS NOT NULL OR
   Day5OT IS NOT NULL OR
   Day6Reg IS NOT NULL OR
   Day6OT IS NOT NULL OR
   Day7Reg IS NOT NULL OR
   Day7OT IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY UserName
```

Comment: Does it really return `username, NULL` or is the record missing entirely?

Comment: The results are empty. But I want it to have at least one row (with a blank string for username and a 0 for ttlTotal) if there are no matching rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the whole `sum()` in `isnull()` or `coalesce()` (the ANSI standard with equivalent functionality):

```
SELECT
  UserName,
  COALESCE(SUM(ifNull(Day1Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day2Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day3Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day4Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day5Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day6Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day7Reg, 0) +
      ifNull(Day1OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day2OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day3OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day4OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day5OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day6OT, 0) +
      ifNull(Day7OT, 0)), 0) as ttlTotal
```

As a note though.  Your data structure is denormalized.  Often such queries would be much easier with a normalized data structure.  That is, instead of storing information about seven days in different columns, store the information in different rows.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. As for the 7 columns, I know, but each row is a different week.

Answer (score 0):

It would be *so* much easier if those column were `NOT NULL` and you forced them to be zero if they had no value.

`NULL` values are meant for "not available" or "not applicable", neither of which is relevant to a day where you worked no hours or no overtime.

Then your query would be the much simpler:

```
select UserName, sum(Day1Reg + Day2Reg + ... + Day7OT) as ttlTotal
from weeks
where RecNum = 1
group by UserName
```